# shaded .jar is installed

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-shade-plugin

Is there any way to disable creation of shaded jar when installing in maven?

I tried

```
<shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>
```

but it is still there.

Any idea? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from writing your own plugin to detach the artifact from the project, I can't think of a way to do this.

There should be a way to detach the artifact from the build, but it would definitely involve hacking around...

Perhaps you should try outputting the artifact to a different directory than `${project.build.directory}`, by using `<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/shaded-jar</outputDirectory>`, or something along those lines. If this doesn't do it and Maven still installs and deploys it, then you could invoke the `maven-antrun-plugin` and just move the artifact from the `${project.build.directory}` directory to `${project.build.directory}/shaded-jar`, or something.